# Access violation issue in Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, debugging, crash, windbg, crash-dumps

We are having Silverlight application which shows live data from the service onto the client.

Over a period of time we see that application gets hung and on refresh the IE crashes with with the error message saying internet has stopped working.\

On taking the dump and analyzing it using debugdiag we found that the callstack of it shows,

```
0x00000000
npctrl!ComAutomationCheckCrossApartmentAccess+d079
mshtml!ReleaseInterface+a
mshtml!CAttrArray::FreeSpecial2+e4
mshtml!CMarkup::BreakAASpecial+f
mshtml!CMarkup::BreakCircularMemoryReferences+eb
mshtml!CMarkup::UnloadContents+36f
mshtml!CMarkup::TearDownMarkupHelper+53
mshtml!CMarkup::TearDownMarkup+54
mshtml!COmWindowProxy::SwitchMarkup+5c5
mshtml!CMarkup::SetInteractiveInternal+134
mshtml!CMarkup::RequestReadystateInteractive+6c
mshtml!CMarkup::BlockScriptExecutionHelper+162
mshtml!CHtmPost::Exec+418
mshtml!CHtmPost::Run+15
mshtml!PostManExecute+1fd
mshtml!PostManResume+f8
mshtml!CHtmPost::OnDwnChanCallback+10
mshtml!CDwnChan::OnMethodCall+19
mshtml!GlobalWndOnMethodCall+104
mshtml!GlobalWndProc+183
user32!InternalCallWinProc+28
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+150
user32!DispatchMessageWorker+306
user32!DispatchMessageW+f
ieframe!CTabWindow::_TabWindowThreadProc+54c
ieframe!LCIETab_ThreadProc+2c1
iertutil!CIsoScope::RegisterThread+ab
kernel32!BaseThreadStart+37
```

We are not able to analyze this any further as it does not give a meaningful analysis.

What is npctrl.dll and why it? Why is it giving ComAutomationCheckCrossApartmentAccess error?

Comment: The npctrl.dll is a Microsoft Silverlight [add-on](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2406108)

Comment: @sergmat: Any idea on why is it crashing?